Point inside an isosceles triangle through which sum of distances of vertices is minimum?
So how can I locate a point inside an isosceles traingle (or any general traingle) through sum of distances of its vertices is minimum
Though coordinate geometry it's easy to find sum of square of distances to be minimum as it eliminates the root so easy to differentiate but sum of distances are giving me trouble as it's get messy and still not able to locate point so any other method or idea I could work Upon?

It is Fermat point.

If an angle is greater than 120 degrees then the minimum point is simply the vertex of that angle.
